# Use cases to select subelements by Regex

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, filtering, regular-expressions

I have a nested list and would like to select a sub set of lists using a RegEx and I would prefer to use patterns (mainly for readability).

```
list = {
  {"1", "abc"},
  {"2", "abd"},
  {"3", "c"}
}
```

What I would like to use looks like:

```
Cases[list, {_, *Use a RegEx here for "ab"*}]
```

Actually, for my specific case substring matching would be sufficient.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You need `StringMatchQ[]`: `Cases[{{"1", "abc"}, {"2", "abd"}, {"3", "c"}}, {_, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, RegularExpression["ab."]]}]`

Comment: Works like charm. For my case even sufficient is: `Cases[{{"1", "abc"}, {"2", "abd"}, {"3", "c"}},{_, s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "ab"]}]`

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the shorter one (as well as `Cases[{{"1", "abc"}, {"2", "abd"}, {"3", "c"}}, {_, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "ab*"]}]`), but you did ask for regex... ;)

Comment: Hopefully not too stupid, but why `{_, s_String /;  "ab" ~~ ___}` is not returning anything?

Comment: Because you're mixing patterns with string patterns. That's why you confine the string patterns to string functions: `Cases[{{"1", "abc"}, {"2", "abd"}, {"3", "c"}}, {_, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "ab" ~~ ___]}]`

Comment: I see - thanks a lot! Then I would gladly like to accept your answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good place to use the curried "operator form" of one of the string match predicates, such as:

```
Cases[list, {_, _?(StringMatchQ["ab*"])}]
(* {{"1", "abc"}, {"2", "abd"}} *)
```

Comment: I keep forgetting these curried forms; I was accustomed to not having them in older versions... :)